# python paho-mqtt publish NULL value

Tags: python-2.7, csv, paho

I'm trying to read from a CSV file and publish row values using paho-mqtt but broker log responds that it cannot update the topic with NULL

```
for r in reader:
publish.single(strMqttChannel, r[2], hostname=strMqttBroker, auth={'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
```

r[2] is in the simplest case i tried 1
it can also be a minus decimal like -1.5
`str(r[2])` also doesn't work
If I pass the value without variable it works like charm:

```
publish.single(strMqttChannel, "1", hostname=strMqttBroker, auth={'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r[2].strip()
```

did the trick....